# Project Online - Enterprise Custom Field Not Calculating Formula Correctly?

Tags: ms-project

I am new to MS Project (~1 week experience) and could use some help with an Enterprise Custom Field I'm trying to create. I'm using Project through Project Web App in Office 365 (I assume this is Project 2016?) and trying to create an Enterprise Custom Field at the Project level of type Text to calculate a Project Size based on Work. I have created the following formula in my custom field:

```
IIf([Work] > 1000, "XL", IIf([Work] > 160, "L", IIf([Work] > 40, "M", "S")))
```

Work is input at the Task level in Hours and is displayed at the Project level in Hours in my view in Project Center. My expectation is that the Work displayed at the project level is a sum of Work that has been input at the Task level for all tasks associated to the project and thus I should be able to use this formula to automatically populate my Project Size field. What I'm actually seeing is that some projects display nothing in Project Size (even though they have non-zero values for Work on tasks) and any project that actually displays a value always displays XL.

Am I missing something about how Enterprise Calculated Fields work in Project or is there something wrong in my formula syntax? Thanks in advance for any assistance.

**Update:** I added another calculated field (Numeric) that has a formula of [Work]. When I added it to my Project Center view, none of the projects had a value in this column. I went into a project for which I already had 1 placeholder task created and deleted the task. I then added the task back with the same information as the deleted task and saved/published it. After saving/publishing, the project still has no value in the Project Size column, however, my new calculated field is populated with the correct value of Work (in minutes as @Tom-Boyle stated). In addition, if I go back into the project and select Project Details from the left navigation, I do see a correctly calculated Project Size on that page.

Comment: I would guess that you want to use something like **val([Work])**

Comment: 1. Not sure how formula roll-ups work in POL, but I expect you've verified the "calculation for task and group summary rows."  2. Assuming work is stored in minutes (as in mpp); and assuming the criteria in your formula are hours, you'll need a "/60" after each [Work] term.

Comment: I can't find the "calculation for task and group summary rows" setting?

Comment: OK.   According to this: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-or-edit-an-enterprise-custom-field-67cf8ad5-11a2-419b-b320-a6b3a9a06336  ,"Note that summary row calculation is not available with a field type of Text."  That might be your answer....

Comment: After reading that help page, I think it's not available because I'm using an entity type of Project rather than Task or Resource.